# Can't clear listbox

Tags: c#

I'm working on a `new` button that resets the form application when clicked. 
However I've run into a problem that I can't seem to solve.

Basically what I want to do is to clear the list boxes when the the button new is clicked.

The New button should initialize the program exactly as at
start-up (but without restarting the application). If data has not
been saved, allow the user (through a MessageBox) to confirm
proceeding without saving current data or go back to the current
session.

Here is how I tried it:

```
private void mnuNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        for (int index = 0; index < animalmgr.Count; index++)
        {
            Animal animal = animalmgr.GetAt(index);

            if (animal != null)
            {
                // error message
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("The data will be lost. Continue?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    InitializeGUI();
                }    
                else if  (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                }
            }

            else
            {
                ClearLists();  <--------This does not work!
            }
        }
    }


private void InitializeGUI()
        {
            animalmgr.DeleteAll();
            Resultlst.Items.Clear();
            foodItemslst.Items.Clear();
        }

public void  ClearLists()
        {
            Gendercmb.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GenderType));
            Categorylst.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categorytype));
            Resultlst.Items.Clear();
            foodItemslst.Items.Clear();
        }
```

**What does work**: It does display a messagebox if the `animal` object is not null.

**What does NOT work:** When I load a file and display the object on the listbox, the `new` button does NOT clear the list. The reason is because the `animal` object is null after loading a file and displaying, but it should call the `else` and clear the list, but it doesn't.

**UPDATE:**

The problem is NOT the the `ClearLists()` method. The problem is that the `if statement`, never seem to reach down to call it. The problem is not the `ClearLists()` method itself. The problem is that it never is called.

Comment: Have you debugged this? Is `animal` actually null?

Comment: first I would start off by placing breakpoints in your code.. then I would debug the code and step through also what is the scope of this `foodItemslst` object..

Comment: If `animal` wasn't null, the `if statement` would be true and display the messagebox

Comment: @MethodMan `foodItemlst` is just another listbox that should be cleared just like the` Resultlst`

Comment: Set the DataSource to null instead of clearing the items

Comment: @Steve I tried `Resultlst.DataSource = null;`it didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Place a MessageBox inside your ClearLists() function just to make sure that the function is being called.

Comment: "This does not work"... can you be more specific? Why not? What doesn't it do?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, `animal = 0`, therefore it is never `null`...

Comment: Animal is never null, and the problem lies elsewhere. Consider revisiting your logic. Also, this is why the debugger exists.

Comment: Make sure your mnuNew_Click() event works. If it does then check number number of elements in animalmgr. If number of elements in animalmge is more than 1 then place a debug point and check where it breaks.

Comment: What is `animalMgr` and what makes you think it will ever return `null` for `GetAt(i)`? Clearly, it never does.

Comment: You need to make a real, compilable, self-contained example showing the problem. You're making statements about what's happening without any reasoning shown. We are currently just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in your logic comparison of

```
animal != null
```

Look at your logic, the line above gives `animal` a value, even if that value is 0. Therefore `animal` is *never* null, because it always has a value.

Comment: That value could be `null`, in theory.

Comment: This is a fair assumption, but the problem lies in code that the OP didn't provide - either `animalmgr` or the `GetAt()` method (if the GetAt() method is provided by Microsoft, please correct me).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public void  ClearLists()
{
    Gendercmb.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GenderType));
    Categorylst.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categorytype));
    Resultlst.DataSource = new List<ListItem>();
    foodItemslst.DataSource = new List<ListItem>();
}
```

Remember, if this is an asp.net webforms application, you also need to call DataBind() dunction on foodItemslst and Resultlst both.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not the method `ClearLists()`

The problem is that the `If-statement` never reaches down to the `else statement`

Comment: Place a MessageBox inside your ClearLists() function just to make sure that the function is being called. Because either of the if  or else statement must be called. Unless your mnuNew_Click() event isn't getting fired at all. OR another case can be animalmgr is empty.

Comment: I tried as you said, and the message box was not displayed. It was as I thought, the `else statement` is never called

Comment: Place your debug point at for loop and check you hit that point and getting inside your for loop.